# Form messing up layout of webpage

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I am beginning a webpage, but I'm having a problem. I added a form with some information to start a login form. I tried adding a margin and padding to the form, but it is still completely messed up. Here is the code for the area that gets messed up, and the form.

```
<div id="body" style="width:100%;height:1000px;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;margin-top: 5px;">
    <div style="width:20%;display:inline-block;text-align:left;border: 2px green solid;"></div>
    <div id="paddingLeft" style="width:4%;display:inline-block"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width: 50%;"></div>
    <div id="paddingRight" style="width:4%;display:inline-block"></div>
    <div id="loginTitle" style="display:inline-block; width: 20%;border:2px green solid;text-align:center;" class="style1">Login</div>

    <div style="width:20%;display:inline-block;text-align:left;height:100px;border: 2px green solid;"></div>
    <div id="paddingLeft2" style="width:4%;display:inline-block;height:100px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width: 50%;height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="paddingRight2" style="width:4%;display:inline-block;height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="loginFormArea" style="display:inline-block; width: 20%;height:100px;border:2px green solid;text-align:center;">
        <form method="get" id="loginForm" style="height: 100%;padding:2px">
            <span class="style1" id="Username" style="display:inline-block; width:40%;">Username:</span>
            <input id="usernameInput" name="Text1" type="text" style="width:40%;display:inline-block;margin-top: 5px;height:15px" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use a CSS file, to edit css inline is just more work...

Comment: I do have a CSS file for the main layout, I like to set everything up inline, then when its right put it in a css file so I don't forget whether it's good or not

Comment: Your layout is a bit confusing, hard to give an answer and know what you want... Check this and let me know what is wrong here. I added what you see in the right side/css. From there maybe easier to give an answer. http://jsfiddle.net/D84jt/

Comment: Here is the website, if it loads properly its very easy to see the formatting problem; www.tqbtest.comlu.com    do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is the boxes on the left should look be touching like the ones on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="bodywrapper" style="width:100%;height:1000px;margin-top: 5px;">
```

instead of:

```
<div id="body" style="width:100%;height:1000px;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;margin-top: 5px;">
```

My suggestion is:

- don't call the id of the div "body". `body` is a structural element in html.
- remove margin left and right. You already say it should be width:100%, so it's unpredictable to add margin on that. You can add padding instead, if you want. That might have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: That didn't change the gap between the top dix of the left section and the bottom div of the left section

Comment: But that div, with `class="bodyDiv Titles"` has no height defined. So the left div being empty, with no text makes it be "small". The right div is equal but has text inside: `<div class="bodyDiv Titles" style="width:20%">Login</div>`

Comment: So once I add the text it should level out?

Comment: I added "Test" to the left one and it made the gap half the side but it didn't get rid of it

Comment: In your website you have classes that you do not have here (and there I see a `height:125px;` on the right `.body .boxes`, try removing that). I suggest you make one div for each box title+content, like that it's easier to have control over them.